# Finding longest path of a tree structure

Tags: java, tree

I have a tree structure that looks like the following:

```
Tree {
   Node root;
}

Node {
   List children;
}
```

And I'm trying to make a method that returns the length of the longest path. I've seen some solutions that work when it's a binary tree, but there is no limit to how many children nodes each node can have and that is where I'm running into problems.

Comment: 1. Be specific about what type of problems. 2. What have you tried other than above mentioned (sort of) template

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I should do somethinkg like this

```
int getLongestPathLength(Node node) {
    if(node == null) return 0;
    int max = 0;
    for(Node child : node.children){
        max = Math.max(getLongestPathLength(child),max);
    }
    return 1+max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for it called the height of the root. You can see the basic algorithm to compute it here (similar to the one given in the previous answer): http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0310-002/lectures/lecture-08.html.